# Как получить доступ к переменной из Redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Есть хранилище

```
const store = {
  markers: [
    { lat: 45, lng: 24, show: true },
    { lat: 46, lng: 23, show: true },
  ],
};
```

нужно массив `markers` передать в `state` компонента

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    loaded: state.markers,
  };
};
```

Если обращаться в `render()` то обратиться к `this.props.loaded` получается, но как обратиться к нему в методе который перед `render()` находится?

```
getLoadedMark(this.props.loaded) { // явно не работает
  console.log(loaded);
}
```

Comment: предоставьте `codesandbox`  и полный код.

Comment: `getLoadedMark(this.props.loaded) { // явно не работает`- вы понимаете что используете параметр как аргумент и это дичь!?

Answer (score 0):

Обращаться к пропсам в параметре метода не очень хорошая идея. Рекомендую вообще убрать это из параметра метода и перенести в тело метода. Так будет правильнее и понятнее.

Чтобы пропсы пробросились в метод (точнее, чтобы был доступ к `props` и `state` внутри функции компонента), необходимо, чтобы этот метод был прибайнден к компоненту. [How do I bind a function to a component instance?](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance)  Есть два простых пути решения проблемы, чтобы `this` был не свой, а компонентский.

Вариант первый - привязка в конструкторе класса (посредством `bind`):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.getLoadedMark = this.getLoadedMark.bind(this);
}
```

После этого внутри метода `getLoadedMark` можно будет заглянуть в `props`, только нужно убрать обращение к пропсам из параметра метода, вот так:

```
getLoadedMark() {
  const { loaded } = this.props;
  console.log(loaded);
}
```

Ну и второй вариант, более простой, без использования метода `bind` в конструкторе, просто через стрелочную функцию `=>` пробрасываем `this` в метод. Метод немного видоизменится:

```
getLoadedMark = () => {
  const { loaded } = this.props;
  console.log(loaded);
}
```

---

Дополню ответ небольшим пояснением. Следующий код:

```
const { loaded } = this.props;
```

Эквивалентен следующему коду:

```
const loaded = this.props.loaded;
```

Это [деструктурирующее присваивание](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (Destructuring Assignment), которое позволяет извлекать данные из массивов или объектов при помощи синтаксиса, подобного объявлению массива или литералов в объекте.